# Detecting referral url

Tags: php, asp.net

I can't detect referral url if user type url directly to browser or if he has some anti-virus or firewall which removes referral url. Is it possible to detect when user typed url directly in browser?

Comment: You answer your question, then ask it again.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible.  The definition for the HTTP_REFERER from http://www.php.net/ :

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

If a user types the location into their browser, you will not receive the REFERER.  You can assume that if the HTTP_REFERER is unavailable / empty then the referer was mental capacity + fingertips....

Answer (score 1):

When user types url directly, there is no referral.
Imaging, you just open browser with blank page, and then type some url and open it. What is the referral for this site? blank page? Browser window?)